# PID returned by spawn differs from Process.pid of the child process

Tags: ruby, process, pid, spawn

I want to `spawn` a potentially long running process and save its PID so I can kill it later if needed.
The problem is that the PID I get from `spawn` is not the same I get from `Process.pid` (in the child process). The result of `Process.pid` matches what I see running `ps` in the command line.

Here is the code for parent and child

### parent.rb

```
puts "Hi parent"
pid = spawn "ruby child.rb 10 &"
puts pid
Process.detach(pid)
sleep 3
puts "Bye parent"
```

### child.rb

```
puts "Start pid #{Process.pid}"
sleep ARGV.first.to_i
puts "End pid #{Process.pid}"
```

### Output

```
Hi parent
1886789
Start pid 1886791
Bye parent
End pid 1886791
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the background job operator (`&`) is causing the intermediate process `1886789`. When I remove the background job operator, I get the following output:

```
Hi parent
93185
Start pid 93185
Bye parent
End pid 93185
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about that, but I still need that the process runs in background, any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Testing this a bit, I'm no longer sure I need the `&` operator